# problem with spring boot component scanning

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am writing spring boot application which has two entity classes Teacher and Department. I am using JPA and H2 in-memory database. When i run the application tables are not creating in h2 database. I have specified package to scan using @componentScan annotation but i thinks spring is not finding location of entity classes.

Application class-

```
package com.H2DatabaseDemo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.H2DatabaseDemo")
public class H2DatabaseDemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(H2DatabaseDemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Aauthor Entity-

```
package com.H2DatabaseDemo.model;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

@Entity
public class Author {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    private String title;
    private String body;

    public Author() {}

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    public void setBody(String body) {
        this.body = body;
    }
}
```

Post entity-

```
package com.H2DatabaseDemo.model;

import java.awt.List;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

@Entity
public class Post {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    private String name;

    public Post() {}

    public Post(long id, String name) {         
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;           
    }    

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

[Here is my project directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpLfo.png)

here is my pom.xml file-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.H2DatabaseDemo</groupId>
    <artifactId>H2DatabaseDemo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>H2DatabaseDemo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Stack trace-
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.4.RELEASE)

2018-09-13 18:00:07.448  INFO 12584 --- [           main] c.H.H2DatabaseDemoApplication            : Starting H2DatabaseDemoApplication on DESKTOP-7NILS0D with PID 12584 (D:\springCourse\H2DatabaseDemo\target\classes started by Mrugesh in D:\springCourse\H2DatabaseDemo)
2018-09-13 18:00:07.453  INFO 12584 --- [           main] c.H.H2DatabaseDemoApplication            : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-09-13 18:00:07.539  INFO 12584 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@17c1bced: startup date [Thu Sep 13 18:00:07 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-09-13 18:00:09.114  INFO 12584 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$934327a5] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-09-13 18:00:09.860  INFO 12584 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2018-09-13 18:00:09.892  INFO 12584 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2018-09-13 18:00:09.893  INFO 12584 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.32
2018-09-13 18:00:09.903  INFO 12584 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_171\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_171/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_171/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_171/lib/amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;c:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\Mrugesh\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\Mrugesh\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Mrugesh\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\eclipse;;.]
2018-09-13 18:00:10.046  INFO 12584 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-09-13 18:00:10.047  INFO 12584 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2516 ms
2018-09-13 18:00:10.173  INFO 12584 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet dispatcherServlet mapped to [/]
2018-09-13 18:00:10.179  INFO 12584 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet webServlet mapped to [/console/*]
2018-09-13 18:00:10.188  INFO 12584 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2018-09-13 18:00:10.189  INFO 12584 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2018-09-13 18:00:10.189  INFO 12584 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2018-09-13 18:00:10.189  INFO 12584 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2018-09-13 18:00:10.392  INFO 12584 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2018-09-13 18:00:10.667  INFO 12584 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2018-09-13 18:00:10.733  INFO 12584 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-09-13 18:00:10.754  INFO 12584 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2018-09-13 18:00:10.863  INFO 12584 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.17.Final}
2018-09-13 18:00:10.864  INFO 12584 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2018-09-13 18:00:10.910  INFO 12584 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2018-09-13 18:00:11.034  INFO 12584 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
2018-09-13 18:00:11.581  INFO 12584 --- [           main] o.h.t.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl  : HHH000476: Executing import script 'org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ScriptSourceInputNonExistentImpl@6bcc3f27'
2018-09-13 18:00:11.585  INFO 12584 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-09-13 18:00:11.700  INFO 12584 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-09-13 18:00:12.010  INFO 12584 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@17c1bced: startup date [Thu Sep 13 18:00:07 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-09-13 18:00:12.060  WARN 12584 --- [           main] aWebConfiguration$JpaWebMvcConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2018-09-13 18:00:12.147  INFO 12584 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2018-09-13 18:00:12.149  INFO 12584 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2018-09-13 18:00:12.183  INFO 12584 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-09-13 18:00:12.183  INFO 12584 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-09-13 18:00:12.558  INFO 12584 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2018-09-13 18:00:12.560  INFO 12584 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'dataSource' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2018-09-13 18:00:12.565  INFO 12584 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located MBean 'dataSource': registering with JMX server as MBean [com.zaxxer.hikari:name=dataSource,type=HikariDataSource]
2018-09-13 18:00:12.605  INFO 12584 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2018-09-13 18:00:12.610  INFO 12584 --- [           main] c.H.H2DatabaseDemoApplication            : Started H2DatabaseDemoApplication in 5.598 seconds (JVM running for 6.203)

Comment: You don't need `@ComponentScan` next to that entities aren't components so they won't be detected by component-scanning. Why do you use a `java.awt.List` instead of a `java.util.List` in your entity?

Comment: Your class is not declared as a bean, so its normal that your component scan wouldn't find it, declare your class as @Component

Comment: Entities aren't components and they shouldn't be.

Comment: can you add @Table(name = "post") and @Table(name = "author") and try, also you may not need `@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.H2DatabaseDemo")`, when you add @SpringBootApplication over a class then Spring will search all components at and inside that package?

Comment: Please post your pom.xml, your stack trace and eventually your application.properties file. And replace java.awt.List with List as mentioned before

Comment: Can you post you application properties file

Comment: I think you are missing @Table annnotation like @Table(name="Post")

Comment: `@Table` is optional.

Comment: Error stack trace would help

Comment: @georgesvan I have editrd my post with pom.xm and stack trace. I also tried by putting entity classes inside main package with application class but it is still not working.

Comment: @M.Deinum i added java.awt.List bymistake.

Comment: do you have a configuration class that creates a LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean?

Comment: please upload your project to GitHub. It will be the easier way to fix your bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your entities classes are fine but your H2 console is configured with the default db (***testdb*** if i'm not wrong). You should at least specify the URL in your H2 Console to match your db name or the other way around.

You may try the following approach:

**1** In the `application.properties` file configure H2 console access control:

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:hddemo-app
```

**2** Access the db from http://localhost:8080/h2-console/

**3** Inside the H2 Console, Copy and paste `jdbc:h2:mem:hddemo-app` in the **JDBC URL** field. Leave the password field empty and click the **connect** button.

**4** You should see the entity you specified in your project as a table.

Answer (score 0):

Try configurate

> hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto

value to be create by adding following line in the application.properties.

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

I have the same problem so I tried this and it works.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

In Spring you have two annotations for scanning:
 - `ComponentScan` for scanning `Component` annotated classes and generating beans out of them (https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html), and
 - `EntityScan` for generating information for JPA and others for the entities (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/domain/EntityScan.html)

In your case, since you are trying to generate entitites and not beans/components, you should use `@EntityScan`.

N.B.: Spring also supports auto configuration: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-auto-configuration.html

Comment: He already uses Spring Boot and he uses the correct structure so using `@EntityScan` shouldn't be needed.